Calculate the number of overlapping days for each device using KQL
How can I calculate the number of overlapping days for each device in the given table, considering the time periods (StartDate to EndDate) for each device and check if and how much they overlap.
The query needs to return the total number of overlapping days for each DeviceID.
Datatable (Devices) with some sample data.
let Devices = datatable(DeviceID:string, StartDate:datetime, EndDate:datetime)
[
    "a1", datetime(2024-01-01), datetime(2024-05-03),
    "a1", datetime(2024-02-12), datetime(2024-02-18),
    "b1", datetime(2024-06-13), datetime(2024-07-07),
    "b1", datetime(2024-07-08), datetime(2024-07-08),
    "c1", datetime(2024-08-23), datetime(2024-10-10),
    "c1", datetime(2024-09-01), datetime(2024-10-07)
];


Can you provide any code/approach that you have tried so far?

No, unfortunately I don't really have a start. I've been thinking about this for two days but I can't get any further than summarizing on DeviceID. I hope someone can help me with this. (I'm a beginner with KQL)

Can you provide expected output

Arriving late to the party.
There are much simpler, generic and performant solutions for your question.
The solution below will tackle any number of periods per device (and not just two, as in your example).
No need for joins.
In this solution we track the change points (where period starts or ended).
Cumulative sum of the changes gives us the number of periods for each segment.
This solution is suitable for 2 periods (per device).
It can be twitched to match any number of periods.
Please feel free
let Devices = datatable(DeviceID:string, StartDate:datetime, EndDate:datetime)
[
    "a1", datetime(2024-01-01), datetime(2024-05-03),
    "a1", datetime(2024-02-12), datetime(2024-02-18),
    "b1", datetime(2024-06-13), datetime(2024-07-07),
    "b1", datetime(2024-07-08), datetime(2024-07-08),
    "c1", datetime(2024-08-23), datetime(2024-10-10),
    "c1", datetime(2024-09-01), datetime(2024-10-07)
];
Devices
| mv-expand delta = dynamic([1, -1]) to typeof(int)
           ,day = pack_array(StartDate, EndDate + 1d) to typeof(datetime)
| summarize delta = sum(delta) by DeviceID, day
| partition hint.strategy=native by DeviceID 
  (
    order by day asc 
    | extend cumsum = row_cumsum(delta), next_day = next(day)
  )
| summarize OverlappingDays = sumif(next_day - day, cumsum >= 2) / 1d by DeviceID
| order by DeviceID asc




DeviceID
OverlappingDays




a1
7


b1
0


c1
37





Calculate the number of overlapping days for each device using KQL

You can do that using below KQL Query, where I have table your input into table Rith_Table:
Rith_Table
| join kind = inner (Rith_Table) on DeviceID
| where StartDate != StartDate1 or EndDate != EndDate1 
| where StartDate < EndDate1 and StartDate1 < EndDate
| extend test_start = iif(StartDate > StartDate1, StartDate, StartDate1), test_end = iif(EndDate < EndDate1, EndDate, EndDate1)
| where test_start <= test_end 
| extend rith = datetime_diff('day', test_end, test_start) + 1 
| summarize Dev_Ovlaping_days = sum(rith)/2 by DeviceID
| join kind = fullouter (Rith_Table|distinct DeviceID) on DeviceID
| extend Dev_Ovlaping_days = iif(isempty(Dev_Ovlaping_days),"0", tostring(Dev_Ovlaping_days))
| project-away DeviceID
| project-rename DeviceID=DeviceID1

Output:

Fiddle.
